# How to retrieve spam comments in drupal DB to delete them using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, spam

I want to retrieve all spam comments in my Drupal DB to remove them using SQL `DELETE` statement. 
I cannot find how comments are marked  as spams in Drupal DB's `comment` table. 
The only relevant column in `comment` table is `status`, which takes value 0 when the comment is unpublished. 
But the unpublished comment can be either a legitimate comment (i.e. not yet approved), or a spam comment.

**So, how to retrieve all spam comments by SQL to delete them from comments table ?**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the spam module to flag spam? Drupal version and modules in use here would be helpful...

If so check the tables that the spam module creates, (I *think* what you're looking for is a table called 'spam_tracker') and look for the relevant foreign key ('content_id'?).

Then it is just a case of adding a left join to your delete query.